# Cannot mount windows partitions

Tags: dual-boot, mount, hibernate

I dual booted ubuntu but somehow my windows was hibernated and then i couldn't mount the partitions. I used ntfsfix but still couldn't mount the /dev/sda5 where my window is also when i restart my pc windows does not show up in the boot menu. How do i open up windows now? i have tried remove_hiberfile but it is not possible to do so from ubuntu since it cannot mount the hibernated windows partition.
PS : windows is not showing up in boot menu. So i am not able to open up windows and shut it down.

Comment: You need to shut down Windows by making it bootable again. You should not access a NTFS partition that is not cleanly shut down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)